# How to give create session privileges to a user in mysql

Tags: mysql, session, privileges

I am unable to give create session privileges to a newly created user. I am using mysql version 8.0.22.
I have tried "GRANT CREATE SESSION TO user_name"; but it's not throwing an error ERROR 1064 (42000).

Comment: Look for that privilege in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html Does it exist

Comment: Then, any other command instead of this? and what a newly created use can do without session privilege?

Comment: Maybe if you told us what issue/problem/situation you are trying to solve we may be able to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I want to create a user and assign few privileges to him. Here, after login from newly created user, I am unable to see any database.

Comment: Ok, so show us the code you used to create a user

Comment: I used: CREATE USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY 'password'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching few documentation I have found that there is no CREATE SESSION privilege in mysql 8.0 as @RiggsFolly said. So

To give all privileges:

> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO user_name;

[MYSQL 8.0 reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-accounts.html#creating-accounts-granting-privileges)